# QSettings clear, what does it do?

Tags: qt, qsettings

The doc said about the `QSettings::clear` function as:

> Removes all entries in the primary location associated to this
>   QSettings object.
>
> Entries in fallback locations are not removed.

But what does this mean? what's the primary location and fall back location???

Comment: The docs explain the fallback mechanism: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html#fallback-mechanism

Answer (score 5):

The primary location depends on the OS and your settings. For Windows this is the registry, etc. From the documentation of `QSettings`:

> Let's assume that you have created a QSettings object with the organization name MySoft and the application name Star Runner. When you look up a value, up to four locations are searched in that order:
>
> - a user-specific location for the Star Runner application
> - a user-specific location for all applications by MySoft
> - a system-wide location for the Star Runner application
> - a system-wide location for all applications by MySoft

The primary location is the most specific one: usually an user-specific location for your application.

You can provide shared default values for all users/applications. But they are not deleted if you call `clear()`. Just the user **and** application specific values are cleared.

### Example

If you initialise the `QSettings` object with the company and application name or using the default constructor, the primary values are the application **and** user specific values. This the the case for most applications. If you just create an `QSettings` object using the default constructor, the values from `QApplication` (application name, and organization name) are used.

```
QSettings settings("MySoft", "Star Runner");
settings.clear();
// or
QSettings settings(); // use the values from QApplication
settings.clear();
```

If you initialize the `QSettings` object with other values, you can choose another primary "store":

```
QSettings settings("MySoft");
settings.clear(); // clears values for whole company if possible.

QSettings settings(QSettings::SystemScope, "MySoft", "Star Runner");
settings.clear(); // clears system wide settings for the application.

QSettings settings(QSettings::SystemScope, "MySoft");
settings.clear(); // clears system wide settings for the company.
```

This last three cases are rare and make not much sense. Also the application needs the permission to write to the system wide settings.